# enable and disable textfield in Processing using Cp5 library

Tags: user-interface, processing, textfield, oscp5

Using Cp5, I'm attempting to create a textfield. I want the user to only be able to edit the textfield after clicking a button. The user is unable to edit the textfield if the button is not pressed.
Does Textfield have a method that can assist me with this function?
I am asking because I didn't find any documentation for the methods in the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setLock() should do what you want to do:

```
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;

String textValue = "";

public void lock() {
  cp5.get(Textfield.class, "textField").setLock(true);
}

public void unlock() {
  cp5.get(Textfield.class, "textField").setLock(false);
}

void setup() {
  size(700, 400);
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  PFont font = createFont("arial", 20);
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

  cp5.addTextfield("textField")
    .setPosition(60, 100)
    .setSize(150, 30)
    .setFont(createFont("arial", 18))
    .setAutoClear(false)
    .setLock(false);
  ;

  cp5.addBang("lock")
    .setPosition(240, 100)
    .setSize(60, 30)
    .getCaptionLabel().align(ControlP5.CENTER, ControlP5.CENTER)
    ;

  cp5.addBang("unlock")
    .setPosition(330, 100)
    .setSize(60, 30)
    .getCaptionLabel().align(ControlP5.CENTER, ControlP5.CENTER)
    ;
  textFont(font);
}

void draw() {
  
}
```